# How do I get SDL Audio working on 32 bit?

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have been struggling with an SDL audio problem for a few weeks now. I have two installations:
1. Ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit)
2. Ubuntu 11.04 (32 bit)
Both are more or less clean installations running on Oracle VM VirtualBox.

On the 64 bit version my own application using SDL is running without any problem, on the 32 bit installation however it keeps stopping when I try to start SDL sound, it complains that it can't open any audio device.

I tried searching on the above and have noticed different issues with games using SDL sound, so far I have not found any answer that solves my issues.

Both installations have libsdl1.2debian and libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio installed.
Also I have had the same issues in 'real' Ubuntu installations, but moved to VirtualBox to simplify testing and have a clean installation for both.

Any help is very much appreciated.
Cheers, Marcel.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out what the problem was, I post it here just to close my question and maybe help anyone else having the same issue:

I had downloaded the SDL sources to my ubuntu installation and installed SDL manually (using ./configure, make, make install), I guess this did not agree with the already available default installation. When I now uninstalled the 'manual' version (make uninstall) and installed the library libsdl1.2-dev on top of the already installed libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio and libsdl1.2debian. Everything works fine and I can also build my app without any problems.

Cheers, Marcel.